# class Not Found Error when I extending my class with java.awt.Frame

Tags: java, package

I can't understand why this error is coming

```
class Temp extends java.awt.Frame
{
Frame f = new Frame(); // error is coming in this line 
// code//
}
```

I know this is silly one but can't getting reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you're creating a Frame if you're *extending* Frame. But in any case, are you  importing java.awt.* or java.awt.Frame?

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat Temp.java; java Temp
import java.awt.*;
class Temp extends java.awt.Frame
{
Frame f = new Frame(); // error is coming in this line 
// code//
public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("this is a " + new Temp());
}
}
this is a Temp[frame0,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
```

Comment: import statement not needed if fully qualified path is written

Comment: you're right, but he only fully qualified it in the extends statement

Comment: i want to know is there is any mandatory to import java.awt.Frame when i am fully qualified the path in extends...
if u explain this that would help me ...

Comment: no, but if you don't you'll have to specify it everywhere you use it, such as java.awt.Frame f = new java.awt.Frame();